# Debugging email connection

Tags: php

I am using XAMPP V 1.7.7; Control Panel 3; Windows 7, Service Pack 1. and Outlook

I am trying to set up an email connection using 'sendmail' -  and am now at the point where everything is finally working - except I now get an entry in the Debug log:

```
12/04/23 21:10:55 ** From address not verified - see http://www.btyahoo.com/verify<EOL>
```

This is the code and set-up so far:

php.ini:

```
    [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.btinternet.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = someone@btinternet.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=mail.btinternet.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

; default_domain=localhost

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=someone@btinternet.com
auth_password=******

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

;pop3_server=
;pop3_username=
;pop3_password=
; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=someone@btinternt.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

php code:

```
<?php   
$email_to = "someone@btinternet.com";
$name=$row['name'];
$email=$row['email'];
$phone=$row['mobtel'];
$email_from = 'someone@btinternet.com';
$email_subject = "Feedback from website";

$message=("Name:  ").$name. ("\r\n") . ("Email:  ") .$email . ("\r\n") . ("Phone:  ") .$phone;


$sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message);


?>
```

The queston I ask is - the 'from address' is correct because it is my own email address. So what is happening?

I would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is because you have no `From` header defined in your message and your SMTP server is expecting one.  The `MAIL FROM` command in SMTP is probably using your address, but your email should have a `From` header too.  `mail()` accepts a header block (lines separated by `\r\n`) as its fourth parameter.

```
$headers = "From: $your_email_address";
$sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
```

The other possiblity is that your SMTP server is not accepting your authentication string as specified in your sendmail.ini

Comment: Thanks for this. I have altered the php and added a $headers with the appropriate email address but I still get the same 'error'  <br /> `code`12/04/25 15:18:38 ** From address not verified - see http://www.btyahoo.com/verify<EOL>`code`

Comment: Thanks so much: I have eventually tracked it down and it now works successfully. I am grateful. Many Thanks.